# Помогите понять код : docker run -d -p 5050:5000 training/webapp python app.py

Tags: linux, bash, docker, port

В методичке есть такой код:

```
dev@ubuntu:~$ docker run -d -p 5050:5000 training/webapp python app.py
```

Цитата-описание:

> Этой командой docker автоматически находит в официальном репозитории
>   образ training/webapp, скачивает его и все необходимые слои, запускает
>   контейнер и приложение app.py в виде демона (-d). Всё это смотрит во
>   внешний мир через порт 5050 и во внутренний (для сообщения контейнеров
>   друг с другом) через порт 5000 (-p 5050:5000).

Стало быть после запуска контейнера, можно открыть браузер, там `localhost:5050` и он выведет 'Hello World!'. Это понятно. Это обращение к внешнему порту контейнера. А что за внутренний порт 5000? Что значит для сообщения контейнеров друг с другом? Если например запустить 2й контейнер, например с браузером, то уже надо будет писать `localhost:5000` для вывода  в этом браузере из контейнера нашего 'Hello World'? Я правильно понимаю? Но если так, то почему не к 5050? Ведь по сути другой контейнер для 1го также является внешним приложением, как и браузер из системы-хоста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Когда вы стартуете контейнер, то приложение внутри контейнера тоже запускается на определенном порту. Проброс внешнего на внутренний порт происходит благодаря NAT через iptables (один из вариантов).
- Для внутреннего сообщения контейнеров - это значит, что если запустите 2 контейнера, то можно сделать так, что они будут общаться друг с другом напрямую - минуя iptables и NAT. Это очень часто используется для подключения web-приложения к базе данных. Один контейнер - приложение, второй - база данных. БД открывает внутренний порт (например, 3306 для mysql) и приложение подключается к внутреннему порту, который открыла БД.
- Если вы запустите второй контейнер - вы не сможете использовать внешний порт 5000 для второго контейнера, если первый уже запущен.

Вообще идея внутренний порт для контейнера - это просто изолированный порт от основной системы.